# Using Interface along with dialogs in android

Tags: android, android-dialog

**What i am doing** ::

- I have a button in onclick of it i am popping a dialog
- The `UniversalDialog.java` has two logics
  `alertDialog.setNegativeButton` & `alertDialog.setPositiveButton`

**What i an trying to do**::

- I want to add the implementation code (inner logic) inside
  `alertDialog.setNegativeButton` & `alertDialog.setPositiveButton` in
  a interface that is defined in mainActivity
- how can i achieve this

---

**MainActivity.java**(*my main activity*)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btn1;
    UniversalDialog dialog; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        dialog = new UniversalDialog(MainActivity.this);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            dialog.showAlert();

            break;
        }
    }
```

}

**UniversalDialog.java**(*the class i have a dialog functionality*)

```
public class UniversalDialog  {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final String dialogTitle=null;
    private final String dialogMessage=null;
    private boolean dialogFlag=false;

    public UniversalDialog(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;        
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle(dialogTitle);
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        alertDialog.setMessage(dialogMessage);

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Go to home screen
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);    
            }
        });

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("QuitApp", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                //Go to home screen
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(startMain);  
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1) you can pass to the constructor of the object UniversalDialog MainActivity (instead of considering only the context), and invoke the methods of the latter

```
public UniversalDialog(MainActivity activity) {
...
}
```

2) you can implement a particular interface on MainActivity (where you specify the callback methods to be invoked on MainActivity) and go back to UniversalDialog this item

```
public interface ActionInterface {
   public void methodOk();
   public void methodKO();
}

public class MainActivity ... implements ActionInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        dialog = new UniversalDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);
        ...
    }

    public void methodOk() {
     ...
    }

    public void methodKO() {
    ...
    }

}

public class UniversalDialog  {
    public UniversalDialog(Context context, ActionInterface action) {
    ...        
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        ...

       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                action.methodKO();
                ...
            }
        });

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("QuitApp", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                action.methodOk();
                ...
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [+1] ... i think this is what i am looking for ....should this line be changed ......dialog = new UniversalDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this); ..... dialog = new UniversalDialog(MainActivity.this, ----?------); ..... i think constructor arguments are incorrect ....can u check ?

Comment: is correct: the first argument is used to pass context, the second to pass the object that implements the interface

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I correctly understand your intention. I think you now perform the implementation of the dialog actions in the `UniversalDialog` class but you hope it can be done in the `MainActivity` class.

If I'm right, then the problem becomes simple and there are more than one way to do it. Let's take one for example.

Define a inner class in your `MainActivity` and let it implement the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface, whose `onClick` method should take use of the `which` parameter. This `which` parameter helps you to decide which button on the dialog is clicked.

If you don't like inner classes, simply let `MainActivity` implement the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` but I have never tried whether the 2 `onClick` functions (one for `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and the other `OnClickListener`) will conflict.